# What is the fastest way to sort a paragraph?

Tags: sort

You can reflow a paragraph with `gqip` (or `gqap`).

Is the fastest way to sort a paragraph `vip:sort<cr>`? Or is there some shorter keystroke for sorting?

Comment: Afaik there is no mapping that sorts given lines.  _(at least `:helpgrep sort` didn't turn up anything in the change.txt file)_

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could define a "sort lines" operator like this:

```
function! s:SortLinesOpFunc(...)
    '[,']sort
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> \s :<C-u>set operatorfunc=<SID>SortLinesOpFunc<CR>g@
```

`\sip` will sort the paragraph under the cursor and, in general, `\s{motion}` will sort the lines moved over by `{motion}`, inclusively.

See `:help :map-operator`.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a simple normal mode mapping:

```
nnoremap <key> :'{,'}sort<CR>

usage from normal mode: <key>
```

or a more flexible visual mode mapping:

```
xnoremap <key> :sort<CR>

usage from normal mode: vip<key>
```